# How to use .Net assembly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, com, activex

all

I have a situation when I need to use one com library(lets call it COMLIB) in IE, in any way (no matter). I usually used to do it like this:
var obj = new ActiveXObject("SomeProg.Id");

The problem is COMLIB, I can not obtain it's ProgID. (I'm not very good in com components, because I'm a web developer primarly.. ) I tried to use OLE viewer that comes with VS 2010, but had no luck. Tried to add ProgID to the registry but it didn't work eather.

I came to conclusion that I can create .net assembly (NETASB), add reference to COMLIB, write wrapper for COMLIB, create com server from NETASB, and use it as ActiveX object.

Is it a good approach, or maybe there is some better?

Thank you for interest and help

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes I have it

Comment: Then go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\<yourguid>` or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<yourguid>` and check if there is a `ProgId` subkey there.

Comment: @SimonMourier I was finding this guid in 4 different places in registry, and there were no PROGId's around in the same leaf  :       HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{8FBDB6A4-8E26-4ACA-8BB4-09EB4FD66373}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{8FBDB6A4-8E26-4ACA-8BB4-09EB4FD66373}

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{8FBDB6A4-8E26-4ACA-8BB4-09EB4FD66373}

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{8FBDB6A4-8E26-4ACA-8BB4-09EB4FD66373}

Comment: Ok, so this guid is not a CLSID, but a TypeLib id (type library id). That's a different guid. You need the CLSID.

Comment: @SimonMourier Sorry for the delay, problem resolved. We asked dll owners and they rebuilt dll with progid. Thank you for support